# Change Xubuntu icon theme from Cubic chroot

Tags: xubuntu, icons, chroot

I am using Cubic to customize Xubuntu 18.04. I want to change the icon theme to Paper. I have  installed it, but cannot configure it. I have tried commands such as `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Paper'`, but they are not of much help since Xubuntu obviously uses the Xcfe desktop environment. Is there any way to change the icon set inside chroot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This trick may help you, as the default icon theme in Xubuntu is *Elementary xfce darker*.

1. Create a folder in your home directory named `.icons`.
2. Copy the folder `/usr/shar/icons/Paper` into the folder you've just created.
3. Rename the folder *Paper* as *elementary-xfce-darker*.

In my tests this worked, tell if this does to you as well.

Comment: Thanks! This worked great on an Xubuntu VM. Since this is in the Cubic chroot, there is no home directory because Cubic is meant for making a custom live CD. If the trick you showed me was put into the default home folder configuration, it would probably set Paper as the default icon theme. Do you know where the default home directory configuration is located?

Comment: @thebluefish I'm not sure what you mean by "default home folder configuration", but the trick will also work if you rename the `/usr/share/icons/Paper` to `/usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce-darker`, first you have to rename the later one to other name.

Comment: Thanks, changing it in/user/share/icons worked great!